# Return list from grouped values

Tags: c#, linq

I want to make a table of the top 10 bestselling items. However, when I use GroupBy in my query I can't return a list.

This is the SQL statement that I tested on my database:

```
SELECT itemId, SUM(amountOrdered) AS amount FROM order GROUP BY itemId ORDER BY amount desc LIMIT 10;
```

And this is how I approached it in my project:

```
        public List<Order?> GetBestsellingItems()
        {
            var result = context.Order
                .Include(p => p.Item)
                    .Where(p => p.ItemId== p.Item.ItemId)
                    .GroupBy(p => p.ItemId)
                    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Sum(p => p.AmountOrdered))
                    .Take(10)
                    .ToList();

            return result;
        }
```

The error I get is:
`Cannot implicitly convert type System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Linq.IGrouping<int, Project.Models.Order>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Project.Models.Order?>'`

Comment: Each grouping contains a list, and you're selecting 10 of them. Do you want to combine all the lists into one? If not, what is the expected output?

Comment: If you have a functional SQL statement, why go through the trouble of translating to Linq and adding another layer of indirection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close. Your grouping contains a collection of orders for each Item ID. Once you have reduced the list to the top 10 groups, you need to extract the desired items. Since the group key only contains the Item ID, you need to drill down into the collection of orders, pick one (any will do), and select the linked Item object.

The result will be a list of Items, not a list of Orders.

Try:

```
        public List<Item> GetBestsellingItems()
        {
            var result = context.Order
                .Include(p => p.Item)
                    .GroupBy(p => p.ItemId)
                    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Sum(p => p.AmountOrdered))
                    .Take(10)
                    .Select(g => g.First().Item)
                    .ToList();

            return result;
        }
```

I omitted the `.Where(p => p.ItemId == p.Item.ItemId)` operation, because I don't believe it does anything. If that test ever fails, you have some serious database integrity issues on your hands.

If you also want to return the calculated amounts along with the items, you will need to change the return type to be a list of tuples or custom objects, and then chance the `.Select(...)` to construct each instance using both the item and calculated amount.

Comment: This does the job perfectly and it's clear to me now why it didn't work before, thank you so much!